# А вон там — мавзолей/Мавзолей Ленина

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, ономастика, названия

Как правильно?

> А вон там — мавзолей/Мавзолей Ленина.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Родовое слово ***мавзолей*** является первым словом названия памятника-усыпальницы, поэтому пишется с прописной буквы.

К тому же ответ легко можно найти на [**Грамоте.ру**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]